# Is there a Towelroot alternative for anoriginal Shield Tablet?

Tags: rooting, nvidia-shield

Yes, I am aware that my tablet is old af

Is there a towelroot alternative? I am on the newest Shield ROM version and towelroot doesn't seem to work. It gives an error code (will enter later). I need something like this because (oof) I do not have access to a computer that I can install `adb` on. If at all possible, I would prefer not to lose my stuff... thanks!

Comment: One-click rooters are pretty much dead by now. Root properly with a custom recovery when you have access to a suitable PC.

Comment: @AndyYan that means losing data tho right?

Comment: Sure, unlocking bootloader will wipe your data.